# How do I fire a PHP file using a <iframe>?

Tags: php, iframe

I have a website that I want it to fire a PHP file that's hosted somewhere else, without using any redirects. I think  is the only possible solution, right?

```
<iframe src=“google.com” frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%">   </iframe>
```

This is the code I have so far.

But this seems to slow down the loading speed when its firing the PHP file.

Comment: You could use `JavaScript` to "touch" the file as well ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [include a website in php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224648/include-a-website-in-php-file)

Comment: Of course the website will slow down when you include another website inside of it; that's to be expected.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you can also call the PHP file programatically using PHP with cURL for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should research into [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

With JavaScript, you can do the same thing but without the iFrame tricks.
Here's an example that will "tell the browser to load another page in the background"

```
<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
xhttp.send();
</script>
```

Do keep in mind that browsers have security restrictions, so make sure the php file is on the SAME domain or it will return an error. If you're getting from another website you don't have control of, you'll need to ask the website owner to [enable CORS.](https://enable-cors.org/)

If you want to do this from the server (php talking to php), you should then just use cURL (as stated in the comments by @MarkSkayff)